# how to validate userinput with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, prompt

I have this scenario where i have 4 drop down boxes, where you can choose CM for a carport and a shed, within that carport.

I want to prompt the user with messages/errors in these scenarios:

- the shed is chosen to be wider than it is long.
- the shed is atleast 60cm smaller than the carports in both width and length
- only one of the sheds dimensions being chosen

the form looks like this

```
    <form name="createorder" action="FrontController" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="createorder">
        <br>
        Length of shed:<br>
        <select name="lengthShed">
            <option value="0">I do not want a shed</option>
            <option value="180">180cm</option>
            <option value="210">210cm</option>
            <option value="240">240cm</option>
            <option value="270">270cm</option>
            <option value="300">300cm</option>
            <option value="330">330cm</option>
            <option value="360">360cm</option>
            <option value="390">390cm</option>
            <option value="420">420cm</option>
            <option value="450">450cm</option>
            <option value="480">480cm</option>
            <option value="510">510cm</option>
            <option value="540">540cm</option>
            <option value="570">570cm</option>
            <option value="600">600cm</option>
            <option value="630">630cm</option>
            <option value="660">660cm</option>
            <option value="690">690cm</option>
            <option value="720">720cm</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        Width of shed:<br>
        <select name="widthShed">
            <option value="0">I do not want a shed</option>
            <option value="18=">180cm</option>
            <option value="210">210cm</option>
            <option value="240">240cm</option>
            <option value="270">270cm</option>
            <option value="300">300cm</option>
            <option value="330">330cm</option>
            <option value="360">360cm</option>
            <option value="390">390cm</option>
            <option value="420">420cm</option>
            <option value="450">450cm</option>
            <option value="480">480cm</option>
            <option value="510">510cm</option>
            <option value="540">540cm</option>
            <option value="570">570cm</option>
            <option value="600">600cm</option>
            <option value="630">630cm</option>
            <option value="660">660cm</option>
            <option value="690">690cm</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        Width:<br>
        <select name="width">
            <option value="240">240cm</option>
            <option value="270">270cm</option>
            <option value="300">300cm</option>
            <option value="330">330cm</option>
            <option value="360">360cm</option>
            <option value="390">390cm</option>
            <option value="420">420cm</option>
            <option value="450">450cm</option>
            <option value="480">480cm</option>
            <option value="510">510cm</option>
            <option value="540">540cm</option>
            <option value="570">570cm</option>
            <option value="600">600cm</option>
            <option value="630">630cm</option>
            <option value="660">660cm</option>
            <option value="690">690cm</option>
            <option value="720">720cm</option>
            <option value="750">750cm</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        Length:<br>
        <select name="length">
            <option value="240">240cm</option>
            <option value="270">270cm</option>
            <option value="300">300cm</option>
            <option value="330">330cm</option>
            <option value="360">360cm</option>
            <option value="390">390cm</option>
            <option value="420">420cm</option>
            <option value="450">450cm</option>
            <option value="480">480cm</option>
            <option value="510">510cm</option>
            <option value="540">540cm</option>
            <option value="570">570cm</option>
            <option value="600">600cm</option>
            <option value="630">630cm</option>
            <option value="660">660cm</option>
            <option value="690">690cm</option>
            <option value="720">720cm</option>
            <option value="750">750cm</option>
            <option value="780">780cm</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a function to your `<select>` elements onchange property.

```
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
    selects[i].onchange = function(){
        // Check for your conditions
        // If your warning conditions are met, prompt user
    }
}
```

That is, assuming you want the validation to happen when the user changes one of the select's values.

If you want to validate with a button click, you can instead bind the function to the click event of the button.

```
let button = document.getElementById(buttonID);
button.onclick = function(){
    // Check for your conditions
    // If conditions are met, prompt user
}
```

To prompt the user, you can use a simple `alert()` to which you pass your message. Or make a more elaborate function to do something custom.

As for your conditions, that sounds like commercial math. Might have to split your question in multiple questions here as there are a lot of possible awnsers.

It might be easier for you to add IDs to your selects so you can get them via `document.getElementById(idString)`. You can then get their value through `document.getElementById(idString).value`. And to use it in math solving, you will need to parse the string that the `<select>` will return as value, like so `parseInt(document.getelementById(idString).value)`.

Comment: Seems like I got all i need from this answer, thanks Drumline18!